# Epoch(millisecond) to UTC timestamp conversion adding 2 days to the default date(0001-01-01) in nifi

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi, citus

One of my nifi process is taking data from JSON object and inserting it in postgres table.
I'm currently facing an issue with inserting default time -62135596800000 (0001-01-01) from NiFi to PostgreSQL. I've noticed that when the data is inserted, there's an unexpected addition of 2 days, resulting in the date showing up as 0001-01-03 in PostgreSQL.

Can someone help me in understanding the root cause for this?
Please note that nifi internally converts epoch to UTC while inserting data from JSON to postgres, I am not doing any conversion in nifi process.

Edit:

Here is an example (I have attached screenshots):

1. I am taking a JSON file as an input that has both negative and positive epoch times. I am getting content of JSON file using "GetFile" processor. Here is how JSON file looks like :
   [
   {
   "EndTime": -62135596800000
   },
   {
   "EndTime": -62135596800000
   },
   {
   "EndTime": -62135596800000
   },
   {
   "EndTime": -62135596800000
   },
   {
   "EndTime": 1709320871411
   }
   ]
2. Next, I am using "PutDatabaseRecord" processor to insert this JSON data in a postgres table.[Nifi Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HticS.png)
3. If you see in the screenshot, the date is getting inserted as 0001-01-03 instead of 0001-01-01 in the database.Datatype of column is timestamp. [Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNpgR.png)

Comment: Works for me `select '0001-01-01'::date; 0001-01-01`. Even if I convert to timestamptz, I get `select to_timestamp(-62135596800000/1000); 0001-12-31 16:07:02-07:52:58 BC`. What is the data type for the Postgres table you are inserting into?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have made an edit to the post. I have added one example.

Comment: 1) Obviously something in NiFi is changing the epoch value. Look at the Postgres log and see what the value is when if comes from NiFi. Update your question with the result. 2) Also add to question text the result from `SHOW timezone;` in the Postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your system is probably doing a time zone or other conversion.

As a test in psql:

```
SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'; 
--Make sure the TZ is set to UTC;

select extract(EPOCH  from '01/01/0001 00:00'::timestamp);  
--My system returned -62135596800 - Note that this
--EPOCH is slightly different than yours

select to_timestamp(-62135596800);
--Returned 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000 +00:00
```

Comment: Hi, I have made an edit to the post.